# Doubling a variable numerous times, and adding all iterations of the variable together

Tags: c

EDITED FOR CLARITY'S SAKE. I APOLOGIZE FOR THE CONFUSION :3

Okay, so I'm following an online CS class, and we're supposed to write a program, in C, that will tell you how much money you'd have if you had a penny at the beginning of the month and doubled it every day.

Each day you would get double what you had yesterday PLUS everything from the previous days.

Example: You start with .01 and what to calculate a running total by day 3. So the first day is .01, second day is .02, third day is .04. On day 3 you would have 0.01+0.02+0.04 (.09).

The program intends to calculate this process over the duration of any given month (28 - 31 days).

I'm having a really hard time trying to implement this. I've got it doubling it, but I'm not sure how to the previously-calculated days together.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    /*days represents total days in months*/
    /*pens represents the number of pennies on the first day*/

    long long days;
    long long pens;

    do {
      printf("Enter the number of days in the month: ");
      scanf("%llu", &days);
    } while(days < 28 || days > 31);    

    printf("Enter the initial number of pennies: ");
    scanf("%llu", &pens);

    for (int i=0; i<= days-1; i++) {
      pens += pow(2,i);
      printf("You'll have $%llu\n", pens);
    }
}
```

edit2: Okay, so I think I fixed it thanks to all your awesome advice. I changed the last part to:

```
for (int i=0; i<= days-1; i++)
        {
            pens = pens + (pens * 2);

        }
        total = pens / 100;
        printf("You'll have $%.2f\n", total);

    }
```

Though there is still a slight issue with the output (which, I'm thinking, is due to the data type I'm using?)
It prints out:

You'll have $0.00
You'll have $0.00
You'll have $0.00
You'll have $0.00
You'll have $2.00
You'll have $7.00
You'll have $21.00
You'll have $65.00
You'll have $196.00
You'll have $590.00
You'll have $1771.00
You'll have $5314.00
You'll have $15943.00
You'll have $47829.00
You'll have $143489.00
You'll have $430467.00
You'll have $1291401.00
You'll have $3874204.00

etc.

Pretty good, but I'm betting it's not that accurate since the first few iterations are 0.00.

Comment: I don't understand the setup. How much would you have on day 3?

Comment: @KerrekSB you would have 0.01 + 0.02 + 0.04, assuming you start at day 1 instead of day 0

Comment: @tekknolagi: So the question should be, "I receive a doubling amount of money every day"?

Comment: @KerrekSB sounds right. Edit it if you'd like, though I see no need to. He's new, but he's doing an alright job.

Comment: @KerrekSB though the title does in fact make 0 sense

Comment: @tekknolagi: At the moment, the title is the least of the problems :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB it's not worth wasting both of our time on, don't you think? I understood it, and so did the rest of the people who answered. I'm not saying English and C should degrade horribly, just that this one question isn't worth it.

Comment: re your edit: pens / 100 is integer division. Try pens/100.0 (and total must be a float or double). Also, your braces aren't balanced.

Comment: Thanks so much Jim! changing it from a long to a float, and adding that decimal place did the trick. You're my hero. And what do you mean by balanced? Do you mean they simply don't line up, or is it something other than a stylistic error?

Comment: @Kierkegaurd the typical way of saying "thanks" is accepting the solution that works for you

Answer (score 5):

Well, let's translate what you have to do into pseudocode:

```
var daily_amount = 0.01
var total = daily_amount

iteration_over_days:
    daily_amount *= 2
    total += daily_amount
```

From there, all you need to do is translate to C.

Enjoy!

Instead of using the `long` datatype, you can also start at 1 and then at the end divide by 100: $0.01 -> $1

Comment: This is basically what the OP's code does, and is not correct.

Comment: Is this not what he is trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JimBalter forgot to tag you.

Comment: I don't know ... his or her problem statement says something different from his or her example. It would help if the OP had said what was wrong with his/her output.

Comment: I think he mistyped his English explanation, as his code pretty much says what mine did, and this is a typical problem given out for homework.

Comment: Yeah, I do apologize for that. Any comments on the newly-edited main post? Is it because I'm using long that it's reporting imprecisely?

Comment: @Kierkegaurd no worries. Not sure about the lack of precision, but floating-point anything will always be imprecise. There was a great HN post about this.

Comment: @Kierkegaurd see my suggestion — you can use an integer until you finish, then divide by 100.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following line needs change:

```
pens+=pow(2,i);
```

It should be:

```
pens = pens + (pens * 2)
```

The logic is that if you start with 1 penny on day 1, then it will be something like this

Day 1 :  1 + (1 * 2) = 3 
Day 2 :  3 + (3 * 2) = 9 
Day 3 :  9 + (9 * 2) = 27 
and so on..

I hope this is the logic which you are expecting. By doing pow(2,i), you are just adding square of the day count to your total money each day which does't seem to be the expected logic based on your question.

Comment: 'square of the day count ' -- no, that's `pow(i, 2)`. The problem with `pow(2, i)` is that it isn't multiplied by the initial number of pennies, so it's wrong if that isn't 1.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compute the power each time! Just keep track of a running count and double it every day.

Here's the core of the algorithm you need for `total_days` number of days:

```
typedef unsigned long long int my_uint;

my_uint initial_payment = 1;
my_uint total_pennies = 0;

for (my_uint day_payment = initial_payment, day = 0; days != total_days; ++day)
{
    total_pennies += day_payment;
    day_payment *= 2;
}

// now have total_pennies
```

---

Of course you could notice that 1 + *q* + *q*<sup>2</sup> + *q*<sup>3</sup> + ... + *q*<sup>*N* − 1</sup> is the same as (*q*<sup>*N*</sup> − 1) / (*q* − 1) and thus compute the answer in one single step (e.g. for *q* = 2 in your case and *N* number of days).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you are looking at:

```
total = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
     total += pens;
     pens = pens*2;
}
printf("You'll have $%d\n", total);
```

Comment: `pens += pens*2` is the same as `pens *= 3`. I wonder if the OP is stating the problem correctly.

Comment: I was confused in the beginning, I think above is the code he is asking for - double amount of each day and add up. I have edited it.

Comment: Your edit produces the same result as the OP's code. The OP's problem statement says one thing, but the example says another. It's very unclear.

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear, it's pretty late where I'm at, so I'm probably not at my best. To sum it up succinctly: every day, the initial penny (or amount of pennies) doubles. So first day is .01, next is .02, next is .04, .08, 16, etc. Then I want to add all the days up (.01 + .02 + .04) once we reach the end of the month. This is like my 2nd day at attempting to learn to program, so I'm probably overthinking it.

Comment: @Kierkegaurd That's what your code does ... I've run it and it gives the output you say you want. But that description doesn't match what your question says is the problem statement ... which is adding twice the total to the total.

Comment: The first four days of the input read as:You'll have $2
You'll have $4
You'll have $8
You'll have $16. Firstly, it should start with $.02, not 2--which I'm having trouble formatting. Anyways, the 2nd day should be 2 + (2*2) which would be 6, not just 2*2, which is what it's giving.

Comment: @Kierkegaurd ' so I'm probably overthinking it' -- No, what you're doing is failing to precisely translate your description into code. `pow(2,i)` is `2**days`, but that's not pennies ... the value clearly must change when the initial value of pens isn't 1. See tekknolagi's answer to see how to think as a programmer.

Comment: How does the updated version look? (edited into the main post)

Comment: @Kierkegaurd `$2 You'll have $4 You'll have $8 You'll have $16` ... that's what it says if inital pennies is 1. It's wrong because you iterate from 0 to days-1 instead of 1 to days. It's even more wrong if you set the starting number of pennies to something other than 1.

Comment: Yeah, I got it to change to $3, 9$, $27--which is more accurate. I'm still have trouble getting the pens input of 1 to 0.01, so the output is more accurate ($0.03, $0.09, etc), but I hate to keep troubling you. I don't really know anyone who codes, or knows anything about coding, so I have limited resources for assistance. Thanks.